# Check that files don't contain Unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, unicode

I use this code to check that all files in a directory are free from Unicode and non-printable characters.

Can I improve the structure of the code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import os
import string
import sys

def main(input_folder):
    for directory, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_folder):
        for basename in files:
            path = os.path.join(directory, basename)
            try:
                check_file(path)
            except (ValueError, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
                print(e)
                sys.exit(1)
    print('All files are ok!')


def check_file(path):
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        try:
            data = fp.read()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            raise ValueError('Warning! {} contains non ascii characters'.format(path))
        if not is_printable(data):
            raise ValueError('Warning! {} contains non printable characters'.format(path))


def is_printable(s):
    return all(c in string.printable for c in s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Verify correctness of files.')
    parser.add_argument('--input', required=True, help='Input folder')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.input)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem specification is unclear, and the code may be wrong as a result.  What exactly do you mean by "Unicode characters"?  What if a file contains just two bytes, `0x20` and `0x5D` — is that two ASCII characters (a Space  and a Right Square Bracket `]`), or is that one UTF-16 character (U+205D Tricolon `⁝`)?

Unless you have a clear definition of what you mean by "Unicode", and have a special reason for detecting non-ASCII characters specifically, you may be better off opening the file with a `latin_1` encoding and just checking `is_printable()`.  In UTF-8, any multibyte sequence will have the leading bit set in all but the last byte, which would place it outside the `string.printable` range.  You would reject the same files as before, just with a less specific reason given.

For scalability, it would be better to read fixed-size blocks (perhaps around 8 kB) instead of the entire file at once.  It might also be more efficient to check `c in set(string.printable)` rather than `c in string.printable`.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, it's a nice script. Some minor improvements are possible.

---

`main` is not a very good name for a method that checks the files in a directory tree. The code in the `if __name__ == ...` guard pollutes the global scope. The solution is simple: rename `main` to for example `check_dir_tree`, and move the code in the `if __name__ == ...` guard inside `main`. That way, the `main` function will be in charge of the argument parsing, which is a perfectly reasonable responsibility for a function with this name.

That is, like this:

```
def check_dir_tree(input_folder):
    for directory, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_folder):
        for basename in files:
            path = os.path.join(directory, basename)
            try:
                check_file(path)
            except (ValueError, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
                print(e)
                sys.exit(1)
    print('All files are ok!')


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Verify correctness of files.')
    parser.add_argument('--input', required=True, help='Input folder')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    check_dir_tree(args.input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

It seems to me that the `check_file` function will never actually raise `UnicodeDecodeError`. So the `main` function should not try to catch that, only `ValueError`.

---

`ValueError` is too generic. It might be a good idea to create a custom exception class for your purposes.